# NotesContext not initialized for the thread

Tags: java, xpages

We have a custom control which is calling functions inside a java bean. This java bean uses code we have created some time ago which has ctgclient.jar as its depedencies.

This bean and custom controls works but sometimes we see the following error appearing on the console:

> HTTP JVM: java.lang.IllegalStateException: NotesContext not
>   initialized for the thread.

My thought is that this is caused by the jav library where non serializable objects are being used. Am I correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without code it is anybody's guess. When you create a bean you should:

- make it serializable
- not create new notes threads (initThread) or sessions
- either pass the session as calling parameter
- .or. use the variable resolver
- if you want to use threads use the OpenNTF [threads and jobs](http://www.openntf.org/p/Threads%20and%20Jobs) project as starting point
- not keep any NotesObjects inside like sessions, views, documents

so far my guesses.

Comment: Many thanks for this anwser ( it doesnt realy answer the question but it gives a hint where to search ). The question was passed down to me without handing over the code.

Comment: When someone does that do me I put on my diabolical grin and ask for their credit card and pin. When they puzzled ask what that is about I reply: "Source code or all your money - you pick" :-)